# Use XML in CodeIgniter to retrieve static values

Tags: xml, codeigniter

I wanna use XML file to retrieve static content from it.
E.G:

At "pure" PHP code you write

**$xml = simplexml_load_file("pages/myxml.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");**
And XML file is loaded and then you can use it's content like: **$xml -> menu -> li1**. But when i use the *simplexml_load_file etc*. in CodeIgniter i recieve this: **simplexml_load_file(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "pages/myxml.xml**. How can i make it work to CodeIgniter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely a problem with the path due to CodeIgniter's file structure.

Assuming the "pages" folder is a sub-directory of `/application` then this should work.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file(APPPATH."pages/myxml.xml");
```

If "pages" is on the same level as `/application` (in other words, a sub-directory of the site's "public" folder) then use.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file(FCPATH."pages/myxml.xml");
```

Adjust according to your file structure.

Comment: I have the "pages" folder on the same level as /application. So i tried your 1st suggestion and work. Thank you very much bro!